# 2-D Matrix on heap overloading and read file in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, heap-memory

I have a matrix implementation work. It 's about to read a 10000*118 matrix to my program. And then use operator overloading to return it.

My problem now is that it can't handle a file which has more than 50 rows.
I was using stack and changed to heap now but still have segfault error.

So what I need is to get some help checking my code ,especially the access function.
I have no idea now..Thank you!

### Matrix.cpp

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
Matrix::Matrix(int i, int j) {
    rows=i;
    cols=j;
    data = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * i * j);
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m) {
    rows=m.rows;
    cols=m.cols;
    data=m.data;
}

int Matrix::numRows() {
    return rows;
}

int Matrix::numCols() {
    return cols;
}

float *Matrix::access(const int i, const int j) const {
    return data + (sizeof(float) * (((i * cols) + j) - 1));
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Matrix &m) {
    int i, j;
    os << m.numRows() << " " << m.numCols() <<endl;
    for (i = 0; i < m.numRows(); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m.numCols(); j++) {
            os << *(m.access(i, j)) << "  ";
        }
        os << endl;
    }

    return os;
}



int **Create2D(int row, int col)
{
   int **p = new int* [row];
   for (int j = 0; j < row; j ++)
      p[j] = new int[col];
   return p;
}
// Deletes an array pointed by 'p' that has 'row' number rows
void Delete2D(int **p, int row)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < row; j ++)
      delete [] p[j];
   delete [] p;
}

Matrix Matrix::readMatrix(std::string filename)
{
   int r ,c;

   ifstream matrixFile(filename.c_str());
matrixFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
   matrixFile >> r >> c;
   int **p = Create2D(r, c);

   Matrix* m = new Matrix(r, c);
   for (int i=0;i<r;i++){
      for (int j=0;j<c;j++){
         matrixFile >> p[i][j];
         *(m->access(i,j))= (float)p[i][j];
      }
   }
   matrixFile.close();
   Delete2D(p, r);

   return *m;
}
```

### Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(int i, int j) ;
    Matrix (const Matrix& m) ;

    int numRows ( ) ;
    int numCols ( ) ;

    float *access(const int i, const int j) const ;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Matrix &m) ;

    static Matrix readMatrix ( std::string filename ) ;

private:
    Matrix() { }
    int rows ;
    int cols ;

    float *data ;
} ;

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

Comment: you're using C++, don't use `malloc`, use `new[]`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Could you post a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: This wont help you, but you should not mix up malloc and new. If you write c++ you are better with the new statement, and you forgot to free the memory allocated by malloc

Answer (score 3):

Given this line,

```
return data + (sizeof(float) * (((i * cols) + j) - 1));
```

If `i == j == 0`, it will 
`return data - sizeof(float)`,
then you're access out of bound memory.

Comment: It's actually worse than that. Even if you correct the `-1`, it still betrays a deep misunderstanding of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Beta: It would be better if the OP chose to use vector.

Comment: I think it would be better still if the OP experimented with a 1D array first, and mastered arrays *before* starting to use vector.

Comment: @Beta: that because I saw him **#include <vector>** in his source code. But it shows that he ought to learn 'bout array first. :)